# Windows azure deployment

Tags: azure

I just built a simple hello world windows azure service containing just one web role, I used visual studio 2008 and Windows azure tools for VS 1.2 I am pretty new to this and I have been trying to deploy an application all afternoon now. I'm in australia and deploying in the region Asia anywhere.

I have pretty much followed the info provided on MSDN and it says uploaded 95% then after about ten minutes the deployment disappears. I have tried using the old windows azure developer portal and 30minutes later I can not access the service and it's status is either busy or stopped.

I have the introductory offer for an extra small compute instance on the subscription I am deploying to. Can anyone with experience with windows azure elaborate on the subject of deploying apps and the status on my application, I am very keen to get into the platform and this issue has just about spoiled my weekend.

Comment: How do you deploy? From inside Visual Studio, or using the upload features on the portal? Is there a reason you are using SDK 1.2/VS2008? There are newer versions for both. Try to create a very simple dummy app that uses nothing on the platform (no storage, no diagnostics, etc) and see if you can get that one deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it is related to the UseDevelopmentStorage=true for a connection string. I have accidentally done this a couple of times myself and things just magically don't work and there is no explanation. Missing DLL's are usually a little harder to track down as the application may or may not start depending on where the failure happens. Trace logging and/or infrastructure logging is the best way to find out if the DLL is missing if you can get your application to run that far.

As pointed out already, the best place to start is making the simplest "Hello World!" you possibly can and start extending from there. Yes it will take you a while to make progress but the experiences you gain from this will be invaluable moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to check before deployment
1. Change Roles' Connection Strings to point to Azure Storage instead of UseDevelopmentStorage
2. All References not belong to asp.net framework should be set to "Copy Local=True"

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the deployment is going successfully but that the role instances are not able to start. The most common causes of this are eithe referrences to development storage while deployed (UseDevelopmentStorage=true) or a referrence to an assembly with copylocal!=true.