# Getting Feedback on Windows Azure Web Role that fails to deploy?

Tags: windows, debugging, deployment, azure

I am trying to start up a web role on Windows Azure, but it initializes, goes to busy/stop and continues the  endless loop of busy then stop. I have followed the recommendations of this question : [Windows Azure Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698551/windows-azure-deployment) but still no joy. Of course the application runs nicely in the development fabric when I debug

```
 I have done these things so far:
```

- Turned off the diagnostics to ensure azure storage is not used
- Made sure that copylocal=true is set for each no microsoft assembly.
- Added the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.* references that the sample web role adds
- Did a test run of the basic MVC role and that works.
- Did a dependency analysis to make sure I am explicity referencing all assemblies using this tool [Dependency Visualizer](http://dependencyvisualizer.codeplex.com/) and that they are in the package for deployment. no joy.

Is there a startup log that azure keeps that I can access or similar facility so that I can learn what is failing?

Comment: Which MVC are you using? If MVC3, make sure that key MVC3 .DLL's also have "copy local" set to true.

Comment: at present I am using MVC2 but will upgrade to MVC3 if it will help. At this point I might be willing to part with a body part to see this fly

Comment: turns out this is also true of mvc2. you have to have system.web.mvc to copy local, but not system.web.abstractions and system.web.routing, those need to be supplied by the azure base install

Comment: interesting that the the missing dll turns out to be the microsoft.system.mvc, this normally isn't set to copy local but it required for azure, since my project originated as a local, this is a basic stumble but could only be revealed by upgrading to ultimate and using the intellisense debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have access to Intellitrace?  If you turn that on (VS Ultimate SKU), you can easily download the logs and see why the role is failing to start.  Windows Azure Diagnostics is almost certainly not the issue anymore.  Back before SDK 1.3, it used to run in the same process as your RoleEntryPoint, which meant you a.) could crash your role if it crashed and b.) if your role crashed, it killed the monitor which made it useless for collecting information.  However, the Diagnostics Monitor is now deployed as background task that runs outside of your RoleEntryPoint and it can no longer crash your role.  If you turn on Crash Dump collections and Tracing and you should be able to pick those up.  In theory your Crash Dump should have the stack trace.

Comment: Alas i am not lucky enough to have VS Ultimate. There is no other way to get the azure logs except through this tool?

Comment: WHat I dont understnd is how it can run/work in the development fabric but have an utter failure in the deployment. Shouldnt they be almost the same ? I guess in theory they should, but in practice they aren't

Comment: you're likely missing a .DLL that is not getting deployed to azure

Comment: If you don't want to use Diagnostics as I mentioned, you can RDP into the machine and run the website locally to see the error perhaps.  RDP access is often active even when the instance has reported itself as busy.

Comment: I can never get the instance to start so I am unable to RDP to anything. :( I got budget to upgrade to Ultimate today and am installing it now. hopeuflly intellisense will give me the feedback I need.

Comment: I upgraded to the VS 2010 ultimate sku and using itellesense I was able to find the problem that no other tool was able to provide. It's clear that you pretty much need this version to do any serious Azure development.  Without it, you simply do not get the kind of feedback to debug these and other problems that happen when working with a new tool